# How can I insert an additional argument after the last argument in a prolog procedure?

Tags: prolog, predicate

I am new to learning prolog, and I want to know, if we have some procedure like

```
father("Nic","Adam").
```

and I want to write a function that it will add new value to this

```
father("Nic","Adam","something"..)
```

how can I do this? Using list?  Or what?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: You don't want to do that.

Longer answer: The `father/2` predicate has a certain meaning, namely that for `father(X,Y)` `X` is the father of `Y`. A `father/3` predicate is a different thing altogether. What do you want to achieve with that third argument? Normally, you use additional rules, which derive things from the `father/2` predicate, or even resolve it to a `father/3` argument.

The main question remains: what's the purpose of the third argument? If you want your resolution to work for certain specific 3rd arguments based on the existance of a corresponding `father/2` predicate for example, you could do `father(X, Y, 'something') :- father(X,Y)` which will succeed if you have a corresponding `father/2` fact.

PS: Do learn your terminology. In Prolog we don't speak of *procedures* and we don't write *functions*. Instead we have *predicates*, *facts*, *rules*, ...

PPS: I am not sure which Prolog implementation you are using, but you might want to use `'something'` instead of `"something"`. The latter usually creates a list of character codes, not a string:

```
?- X = 'some'.
X = some.

?- X = "some".
X = [115, 111, 109, 101].
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply writing

```
father(nic, adam).
```

As a predicate already defines it. It is like stating a fact: you *declare* that `father(nic, adam)` is `true`, then you can execute the following with these expected results :

```
?- father(nic, adam).
Yes

?- father(nic, X).
X = adam
```